# Very basic image renaming with regex

Tags: regex

I spent most of yesterday putting together a collection of regular expressions to convert all my image names and paths to lower case. Today, I processed a folder full of files and was surprised to discover that many image names are still capitalized.

So I decided to try it one step at a time, first renaming .jpg's, then .gif's, .png's, etc.

I'm working on a Mac, using Dreamweaver and TextWrangler as my text editors. The following regex works perfectly for jpg's, with one major flaw - it deletes the extension...

```
([\w/-]+)\.jpe?g
\L\1
```

In other words, it changes South-America.jpg to south-america.

How can I change it so that it retains the file extension? I assume I can then just change it to...

```
([\w/-]+)\.png
\L\1
```

...to process png's, etc.

Comment: why not just use a second capturing group for the extension?

Comment: Sounds fine; what would that look like?

Comment: exactly like aelor's or Jerry's answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps capture the extension too?

```
([\w/-]+)(\.jpe?g)
\L\1\2
```

And I think you should be able to use something like this for all the files:

```
([\w/-]+)(\.[^.]+$)
\L\1\2
```

Or if you specifically want to convert those jpegs, pngs and gifs:

```
([\w/-]+)(\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png))
\L\1\2
```

Comment: Perfect; I'll mark it as the right answer in a moment.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

```
([\w\/-]+)(\.jpe?g)
```

and replace with `\L\1\2`

its deleting your extension because you are never saving it in a matchgroup.

Comment: @user3334690 Why would the `/` need to be escaped?

Comment: @Jerry you are actually right, The only thing that needs to be escaped in brackets is a closing bracket, and a minus if it is not initial or final, and a hat if it is initial, AFAIK. And the backslash itself, obviously. I have escaped it because it throws error on regex101

Answer (score 1):

If it's okay for the extension to become lowercase as well, you could just do

```
^(.*)$
\L\1
```

As long as you're certain that all lines contain file names.

If you want to process only certain file formats, use

```
^(.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif))$
\L\1
```

Comment: @ SQB - My files include a variety of content, so I tried your second regex. Unfortunately, it didn't work. But it might just be my programs; most of my regexes work in Dreamweaver or TextWrangler, not both. And I've discovered so many regexes that only work in Notepad, which I can't use on my Mac. ;)

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom You could try it without the `^` and the `$`.

Comment: Great! That means hat your regex dialect doesn't know them, or writes them differently.